# powershell check script for L1tf

Tags: powershell

when I run this script:

```
$SaveExecutionPolicy = Get-ExecutionPolicy 
#  
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Currentuser 

Import-Module .\SpeculationControl.psd1 
Get-SpeculationControlSettings 

Set-ExecutionPolicy $SaveExecutionPolicy -Scope Currentuser
```

it will give the following output:

> For more information about the output below, please refer to
>   https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4074629
>
> Speculation control settings for CVE-2017-5715 [branch target
>   injection]
>
> Hardware support for branch target injection mitigation is present:
>   False Windows OS support for branch target injection mitigation is
>   present: True Windows OS support for branch target injection
>   mitigation is enabled: False Windows OS support for branch target
>   injection mitigation is disabled by system policy: False Windows OS
>   support for branch target injection mitigation is disabled by absence
>   of hardware support: True
>
> Speculation control settings for CVE-2017-5754 [rogue data cache load]
>
> Hardware requires kernel VA shadowing: True Windows OS support for
>   kernel VA shadow is present: True Windows OS support for kernel VA
>   shadow is enabled: True Windows OS support for PCID performance
>   optimization is enabled: True [not required for security]
>
> Speculation control settings for CVE-2018-3639 [speculative store
>   bypass]
>
> Windows OS support for speculative store bypass disable is present:
>   False
>
> Speculation control settings for CVE-2018-3620 [L1 terminal fault]
>
> Hardware is vulnerable to L1 terminal fault: True Windows OS support
>   for L1 terminal fault mitigation is present: False Windows OS support
>   for L1 terminal fault mitigation is enabled: False
>
> Suggested actions
>
> - Install BIOS/firmware update provided by your device OEM that
>     enables hardware support for the branch target injection mitigation.
>
>   - Install the latest available updates for Windows with support for speculation control mitigations.  * Follow the guidance for enabling
>       Windows Client support for speculation control mitigations described
>       in https://support.microsoft.com/help/4073119
>
> BTIHardwarePresent                  : False BTIWindowsSupportPresent
>   : True BTIWindowsSupportEnabled            : False
>   BTIDisabledBySystemPolicy           : False
>   BTIDisabledByNoHardwareSupport      : True KVAShadowRequired
>   : True KVAShadowWindowsSupportPresent      : True
>   KVAShadowWindowsSupportEnabled      : True KVAShadowPcidEnabled
>   : True SSBDWindowsSupportPresent           : False
>   SSBDHardwareVulnerable              :  SSBDHardwarePresent
>   : False SSBDWindowsSupportEnabledSystemWide : False
>   L1TFHardwareVulnerable              : True L1TFWindowsSupportPresent
>   : False L1TFWindowsSupportEnabled           : False L1TFInvalidPteBit 
>   : 0 L1DFlushSupported                   : False

I want to automate in by this:

```
if ($string -like '*L1TFHardwareVulnerable : True*') { }
{
   write-output "1"   (stderr)
}
else
{
   Write-Output "0" (stdout)
}
```

In total script looks like this:

```
$SaveExecutionPolicy = Get-ExecutionPolicy 
#  
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Currentuser 

Import-Module .\SpeculationControl.psd1 
Get-SpeculationControlSettings 

Set-ExecutionPolicy $SaveExecutionPolicy -Scope Currentuser

if ($string -like '*L1TFHardwareVulnerable : True*') { }
{
   write-output "1"
}
else
{
   Write-Output "0"
}
```

Can anyone help me out? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assign the output from `Get-SpeculationControlSettings` to a variable and inspect the properties of that object:

```
$Settings = Get-SpeculationControlSettings 
if($Settings.L1TFHardwareVulnerable -and -not($Settings.L1TFWindowsSupportEnabled))
{
    return 1
}
else
{
    return 0
}
```

for more information on logical operators (like `-and` and `-not`), see the [`about_Logical_Operators` help file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logical_operators)

Comment: Iam a noob at powershell can you explainit more indept? I tryed googleing how to add an variable or a property but there isnt a clear explanation

Comment: You can create a variable by simply assigning something to it with `=`, like on the first line in my example above. The `Get-SpeculationControlSettings` cmdlet returns a single object with a bunch of properties like the `L1TFHardwareVulnerable` property used in the `if` statement above. You can access the value of the individual properties with the `.`, so in the example above `$Settings.L1TFHardwareVulnerable` will be either `$true` or `$false`

Comment: return 1 is a error right and 0 means a correct output?

Comment: @user848535 depends on how you interpret the output

Comment: if the system is vunrable: L1TFHardwareVulnerable              : True and L1TFWindowsSupportPresent output is true then return 0 ass ouput otherwise 1. because anything higher then zero will a error

Comment: No, I mean, how do you plan on running this script and what will you do with it's output?

Comment: If you want to have the exit code of the `powershell` process reflect whether everything is fine or not, you should replace `return 1` with `exit 1` and so on

Comment: Bassicly i want to run this script in a monitor if it failes it wil report a value of 1"stderr" or higher and if it succeeds it needs to report 0 "stdout"

Comment: so it needs to look this?     $SaveExecutionPolicy = Get-ExecutionPolicy 
#  
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Currentuser 
 
Import-Module .\SpeculationControl.psd1 
Get-SpeculationControlSettings 
 
Set-ExecutionPolicy $SaveExecutionPolicy -Scope Currentuser

$Settings = Get-SpeculationControlSettings 
if($Settings.L1TFHardwareVulnerable -and -not($Settings.L1TFWindowsSupportEnabled))
{
    exit 1
}
else
{
    exit 0
}

Comment: am a bit confused, sry am a noob

Comment: So i have a feeling is working for 80% this is how the full script

Comment: $SaveExecutionPolicy = Get-ExecutionPolicy 
#  
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Currentuser 
 
Import-Module .\SpeculationControl.psd1 
$Settings = Get-SpeculationControlSettings 
if($Settings.L1TFHardwareVulnerable -and -not($Settings.L1TFWindowsSupportEnabled))
{
    exit 1
}
else
{
    exit 0
}     
Set-ExecutionPolicy $SaveExecutionPolicy -Scope Currentuser

Comment: the weird thing is that i gives me the output mentioned on top "it will give the following output:" while it doesnt give the output exit 1 or 0

Comment: There is any info about -and -not i tried replacing them with False and true. But both of those command seems to be invalid:(